# Django ListView how loop in one field in the template?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I have django ListView I know I can loop in it like this

```
{% for i in object_list %}
{% i.id %}
{% endfor %}
```

I want to loop in one field only

```
{% for i in object_list.id %}
{% i %}
{% endfor %}
```

update:

my model:

```
class Weather(models.Model):
temperature = models.FloatField(
    validators=[MaxValueValidator(28), MinValueValidator(19)]
)
humidity = models.FloatField(
    validators=[MaxValueValidator(65), MinValueValidator(35)]
)
time_recorded = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
```

ListView:

```
class WeatherListView(ListView):

template_name = "frontend/weather_list.html"
model = Weather
```

I want to loop for each of these fields in different position in the html template so I don't want to loop in the whole list each time for instance if I want to loop in temperature only:
I want to do this:

```
{% for i in object_list.temperature %}
{% i %}
{% endfor %}
```

instead of:

```
{% for i in object_list %}
{% i.temperature %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: please show the model class you trying to loop through and the views code for ListView

Comment: {% for i in object_list %}
        {{ i.temperature }}
    {% endfor %}

Works fine. Why don't you want to write it like that?

Comment: @jaap3 I wanted to optimize my code why loop through the whole context if I just want 1 field especially I'm using it many time in my template and what if my context had several fields not just 3.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think there is a misunderstanding on what `object_list` in the template represents. You are not looping over the "whole context". `object_list` is a variable in the context representing the `QuerySet` of the particular view.

In the case of `WeatherListView` it's `Weather.objects.all()`. So when you write `{% for i in object_list %}` you are looping over all the `Weather` instances in the database.

I'm not sure what you are trying to optimize. Perhaps it's the amount of database queries? In that case I can tell you that `QuerySet`s in Django are evaluated lazily, but once they are evaluated the result is cached. So if you loop over `object_list` once the next time you loop over it will not result in a new database query.